Expansion of functions around a delta function
I know that some functions, like a Gaussian, can approach a delta function in the right limit, for example:
$$\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right)\rightarrow\delta\left(x\right)$$
If I think of it as an expansion in small $\sigma$, what will be the next orders in the series, like the correction order $\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$?
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\approx\delta\left(x\right)+\sigma f_{1}\left(x\right)+\sigma^{2}f_{2}\left(x\right)+....$$

I don't know if you can do such a thing since the Dirac's Delta is not even a function.

you can find an expansion with $f_n(x)=c_n\delta^{(n)}(x)$, but you need to understand it as an asymptotic series

Just write
$$
e^{-\sigma^2 x^2/2} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-\sigma^2 x^2/2)^n}{n!}
$$
and take the Fourier transform on both sides, then use the fact that the Fourier transform of $(-x^2)^n$ is $\sqrt{2\pi}\,\delta^{(2n)}$ (the $n$th derivative) and the Fourier transform of $e^{-\sigma^2 x^2/2}$ is $e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}/\sigma$.
It gives
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}} \,e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\sigma^{2n}}{2^n\,n!} \,\delta^{(2n)}.
$$

That's not very helpful since here we are doing the expansion around $\sigma\rightarrow\infty$ (since in my version $\sigma$ is in the denominator), and the expansion here is around $\sigma \approx 0 $

@YehonatanAvidan. LL 3.14 looks at the Fourier transform which is of the form $e^{-\sigma^2x^2}$. He takes the Fourier transform, expands it around $\sigma=0,$ and finally takes the reverse Fourier transform of the terms.

Thank you md2perpe for further explaining, I was on my phone that day ... @YehonatanAvidan: I now updated to better explain, is it clear now?

Yes I understand now, thanks!

I think I found a way.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}f\left(x\right)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^{2}}f\left(\sigma u\right)du\approx$$
$$\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^{2}}\left(f\left(0\right)+\sigma uf^{\prime}\left(0\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}u^{2}f^{\prime\prime}\left(0\right)\right)du=f\left(0\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}f^{\prime\prime}\left(0\right)$$
And from here
$$\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right)\approx\delta\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\delta^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)$$

Yes, you can do this ! I fully agree with your analysis and your final conclusion. It also follows that not only can one improve the convergence to the Diracr delta function by decreasing $\sigma$, but another approach is to add a term with $x^2$ to the Gaussian, in such a way that a Taylor series term with $x^2$ in $f(x)$ cancels. Try it !
